# Changing Main Activity's Title

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-manifest

I have an issue with changing Main Activity's name. I want to delete it. As first method I used `this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` . It works, but before MainActivity starts `title` shows up and then dissapears. That is annoying, so I tried to edit `Manifest.xml` but one interesting issue appeared. If I set `android:label=""` as `activity` attribute application name dissapears! How that could happen? I'm setting `android:label` for `application` tag, but a app doesn't pay attention to that and takes `android:label` value from `activity` tag. 
How can I fix it? 
Thank you for reading.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Example" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/bobincut">
        <activity
            android:label=""
            android:name="com.example.bakumovies.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: well what did you think would happend?

Comment: didn't get what you mean. Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this in two ways:

The simplest one is to add in your activity's onCreate() this line:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

There's also another solution:

Add this theme to your styles.xml:

```
<style name="NoTitleTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Example">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then, set this theme in your activity (notice the android:theme tag I added here):

```
<activity
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/NoTitleTheme"
        android:name="com.example.bakumovies.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: after adding this `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` to my `theme` app crashes with `NullPointer Exception` :(

Comment: I've found out why `NullPointer Exception` is raised. Your method actually removes whole `ActionBar` instead of removing only title.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted to hide the actionbar too. So, the title you're seeing is the title of preview window. You can disable it. I suggest you to read the following post that clarifies how preview windows work: http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/

If you don't want to read the whole post, add `<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>` to your theme.

Comment: cool, I even didn't know there was such thing like preview. Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this in your activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: this method will cause delay too, because it is executed after `onCreate`. This solution doesn't solve my problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Make a new style that inherits from a `NoTitle` style:

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_splash_logo</item>
</style>
```

Make a new SplashActivity class that applies the style:

```
<activity
  android:name="SplashActivity"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.Splash"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon">
  <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In your SplashActivity, start your real HomeActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // possibly use CLEAR_TOP flag here
    startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.class));
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Finish();
}
```

This will have the effect of suppressing the label at app start, the app name will appear in the launcher and recent apps, you won't get a null ref due to removed `ActionBar`. Which I think satisfies all of your criteria.

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't work as should. If you set `android:label=""` and launch application, it won't appear in MultiTasking bar.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use a "splash" activity technique. Let me know if that works for you.